# Does the set ω + 1 represent a higher infinity that ω? In other words, is ω + 1 countable? What about ω +ω?

Tags: infinity

I answered the first part as follows:

$\omega + 1 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...,  \omega\} = \aleph_0 $
 Since every element of  ω is finite and  one element in $\omega + 1$
 is infinite, they are clearly different infinite numbers. This is also known as an ordinal number. Hence,  $\omega +1$ 
 is countable but it doesn't represent a higher infinity. It is infinity itself.

But when it comes to $\omega + \omega$, I'm a bit confused on how to approach it.

Comment: You have the bijection $\omega+1\to\omega$ given by $\infty\mapsto0, n\mapsto n+1$ for $n\in\omega$.

Comment: For $\omega+\omega\to\omega$ send $n\to 2n$, for $n\in$ the first $\omega$ and $n\mapsto 2n+1$ for $n$ in the second $\omega$ of $\omega+\omega$.

Comment: @flan You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\omega+1$ is an order type (it represents a countable well-order with a unique maximum beyond a copy of $\omega$ while $\omega+\omega$ is two copies of $\omega$ ordered one left to the other. Both represent countable sets in cardinality, so they're not a higher order of infinity.

The set of *all* countable well-orders is of a higher cardinality, called $\omega_1$ (as a well-order) and  $\aleph_1$ (as a cardinal number).